# Buck boost converter output voltage dropping over time

Tags: power-supply, buck, boost

I have a TPS61222 Buck boost voltage converter, in a circuit intended to boost a 3.7V battery source to 5V. The output voltage however, is consistently less than 5V - scoping shows a 4V signal with spikes up to 6v at about 90kHz, low duty cycle.

The current draw is 56mA nominal (into the converter).  The converter powers a charge pump inverter, to generate -5V, along with a number of other devices. The feedback pin voltage should be o.5V, with about 13mV tolerance (as per data sheet) - the value it is showing is more like 0.35-0.42V.

Full schematic and PCB layout are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByDMgvrKWReQMzJpeFBZZmFDZFk)

Comment: You need to do and present more measurements, like actual waveforms, precise dc voltage measurements etc.

Comment: @PlasmaHH While i take your point, I cant get properly characteristic waveforms, as they change constantly, its only the vague shape that is consistent. Similarly for the DC voltages - they drift over time, so there is no precise measurement to be made

Comment: exactly that is the point to show us. If e.g. the reference voltage is drifting, then no wonder everything else is following.

Comment: How much current load is on the Buck converter? Too much or too little current draw can cause it to misbehave.

Comment: @Brendan Simpson the load is approx 40-50 mA depending on the connected sensors. At the supply voltage I'm. Using (3.7) I should he able to draw 200 mA

Comment: @Mauvai Did you make sure to follow the layout suggestions in the datasheet? (also, I said buck earlier, I meant boost). Can you check the output in open circuit mode (no load)? Did you select appropriate components for the regulator (inductor and caps especially)?

Comment: @Brendan Simpson The layout suggestions were followed more or less exactly, along with the components - over specified, and what was recommended. I cant check in open load unfortunately. Our best running theory at the moment is that the output capacitor isn't big enough, and the charge pump load is causing issues - is there any relevancy to this theory?

Comment: Yeah, you can (mostly) always add more decoupling. If your output cap is not large enough to handle the load transients imposed by the charge pump's switching, the output of your boost converter would look crappy. Try adding a large bulk of 10u with some smaller 100n, low ESR, caps in parallel, and "geographically" local to the loads.

Comment: @Brendan Simpson that setup is already in place, local 100n caps and all, which is why I'm curious as to how that could be the problem. Il need to try more output capacitance tomorrow

Comment: Could you try removing the charge pump to measure open circuit performance of the boost converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run a charge pump from another switching device.  In general, it is best not to run this type of device from the output of this type of converter, when the capacities and switching frequencies are close.  The TPS61222 relies on voltage feedback to regulate, and your LM2663 is providing a load which is changing at its switching frequency.

I would try to run the charge pump generating your negative voltage directly off VBatt as a first choice.  If this is completely unacceptable, you could add a cap to the feedback point of the boost converter, although this will slow down the converter's response to changes in input voltage and output load, possibly causing overshoot and undershoot.

Comment: This makes a lot of senses, thanks. I can't run the charge pump from the battery, as I need -5V, 3.7 won't do. Are you suggesting a cap between the feedback pin and the output voltage, or feedback pin and ground?

Comment: Feedback to ground with a time constant much longer than the loop time constant.  Your boost converter reacts to increases in load by increasing the PWM duty cycle, which will increase the output voltage.  Avoid a second switcher running on a first one because the input of the second switcher has a negative dynamic impedance.  When increasing the voltage on the input, the input current does not increase as it would with a passive load; it actually decreases.  I can see it is late in your design, but I would consider flyback topology for a switcher when you need multiple polarities and outputs.

Comment: For the sake of an update - i put a 100nF capacitor across the 110k resistor (RDC2), and while it brought the average voltage up to ~5V, the output was still spiking at about 90kHz. Adding a 47uF Cap across the output (for a total of 57uF, well over the recommended 10uF), retuces the volatge variation enormously (though not completely). It did however raise the average output voltage to 5.3V, which was undesireable. The voltage on the feedback pin is now a very steady 513mV

Comment: You might be able to make a voltage doubler from your charge pump and get away with running directly from VBatt.  I would be worried that the large capacitor in the feedback will effect load regulation.

Comment: Fortunately I am powering  op-amps almost exclusively, so power regulation is not an issue. I'm pretty much where I need to be I think.